# how to enable kde connect to work over firewall of huawei ec315?

Tags: 14.04, networking, kde-apps, kde-connect

I'm using a Huawei wifi dongle to create a small wifi network in my house. I mostly just need a network to use kde-connect on network devices and occasionally share files

Problem: kde-coonect works only if the dongle is plugged into my main PC (where the kde-connect is installed).

The kde-connect can not be accessed if i plug the dongle into a power outlet

Is there a way to fix this?

Dongle model: HUAWEI EC315
[image]

Comment: I was under the impression that KDE Connect could potentially use ports 1714-1764, depending on what ports are used on the phone and on the computer.

Comment: u r correct it should be upto 1764 i did mistake